# Limit rich text box text length to what visibly fits?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I have a C#/WinForms rich textbox for which I need to be able to limit the text entered to what visibly fits within the viewable area.  I know I can limit it by number of characters, but this doesn't achieve the desired effect when we consider things like word wrap, different character widths for non monospace fonts, etc.

I can have an event callback fire when the text changes, but I need a way to know the text is exceeding the viewable area.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your call back you can use [MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx) to determine the lenghth of the string given a font. Then you compare that to the textbox width.

Comment: I'm an idiot..  it's a rich text box, not optionally one.  I'm looking at this though to see if I can apply it somehow...  the methods which take LayoutArea as a factor seem like a possibility..

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last char's offset that fit to your richtextbox's visible area as below:

```
richTextBox1.TextChanged += (sndr, evnt) =>
{
    richTextBox1.Select(0, 0);
    int pos = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(richTextBox1.Width, richTextBox1.Height));

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Graphics.MeasureString` to get the actual width of the string and stop when it reaches the width of your text box

```
Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
SizeF textSize = graphics.MeasureString(myText.Text, this.Font);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/measurestring.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I'm currently trying to do the opposite (resize the rich text box to fit the text set into it), but I came across the function `GetPreferredSize` that you might be able to use. You'd want to save the current RTF text in the box after each legal edit, then on next edit call `GetPreferredSize` to see how big the box would have to be to accommodate the new text. If too big, revert to the saved text...